# UISwitch chang status after reusing the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

Hi I have a `UISwitch` on the prototype cell.

When I change the `UISwitch` to `OFF` and move the cell out of the `UITableView` frame by scrolling and then scroll back - the `UISwitch` is `ON`.

But the changes were made - because when I again call the UITableView controller to be shown on the screen - the `UISwitch` is `OFF`.

The code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SettingsOptionCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"SettingsOptionCell"];
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary new];
    cell.onOption.hidden = NO;

    switch (indexPath.section) {

        case SettingsControllerServiceSection:
            data = self.serviceAttr[indexPath.row];
            break;

        case SettingsControllerStatusSection:
            data = self.statusAttr[indexPath.row];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    cell.captionLabel.text = data[@"name"];
    cell.onOption.on = [data[@"check"] boolValue];
    cell.optionId = data[@"id"];
    cell.updateHandler = ^(){
        if (self.updateHandler) {
            [self update];
            self.updateHandler();
        }
    };
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Might have something to do with your `updateHandler`?

Comment: please share the code for `SettingsOptionCell` class

Comment: set the data-value check to ON or OF in dictionary  when you are changing switch.it is happening because the check-data in dictionary reaming same ,Better you do one thing try to BOOL value when Swith is on or of in dictinoray then i think you problem solved and must make the data array global

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting code.
At first: I do not see where You trying to create cell (dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: only picks object from reusable queue and I do not see where You put it).
At second:

```
cell.onOption.on = [data[@"check"] boolValue];
```

Each time when cell should be placed at tableView You set value of switch from dictionary. Are You shure that You change this value?

P.S. Each time when cell should become visible (You scrolling table) will be called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Almost forget!
 NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary new];
Realy? Why do You need switch than? In objective C nil works great. There is no difference in sending of messages to nil or to empty dictionary (I mean as result).